# Permutation and Combination in Python

Tags: python, sequence, permutation, python-itertools

Does python have some in-built function through which I can generate a sequence like this

For i = 5, how many different ways 0 and 1 can occupy five places like

```
00000
00001
00010
00011
00100
.
.
.
.
11111
```

for i = 6, how many ways 0 and 1 can occupy 6 places:

```
000000
000001
000010
000011
000100
000101
.
.
.
111111
```

I am already familiar with `itertools permutation and combination` but I am not able to generate a sequence like this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product`

```
>>>from itertools import product
>>>list(product([0,1],repeat=5))
```

Comment: awesome! I was looking for something like this.

Comment: Another way I found! from `itertools import product`

`for line in product(range(2), repeat=5):`

   `print list(line)`

Comment: It is the same way..`product` returns an iterator.So one way is for loop or `list(iterator)`. Then range(2) means `[0,1]`

Answer (score 1):

Less elegant, but you can use `permutations` as well:

```
from itertools import permutations
print sorted(list(set(list(permutations('0000011111', 5)))))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[('0', '0', '0', '0', '0'), ('0', '0', '0', '0', '1'), ('0', '0', '0', '1', '0'), ('0', '0', '0', '1', '1'), ('0', '0', '1', '0', '0'), ('0', '0', '1', '0', '1'), ('0', '0', '1', '1', '0'), ('0', '0', '1', '1', '1'), ('0', '1', '0', '0', '0'), ('0', '1', '0', '0', '1'), ('0', '1', '0', '1', '0'), ('0', '1', '0', '1', '1'), ('0', '1', '1', '0', '0'), ('0', '1', '1', '0', '1'), ('0', '1', '1', '1', '0'), ('0', '1', '1', '1', '1'), ('1', '0', '0', '0', '0'), ('1', '0', '0', '0', '1'), ('1', '0', '0', '1', '0'), ('1', '0', '0', '1', '1'), ('1', '0', '1', '0', '0'), ('1', '0', '1', '0', '1'), ('1', '0', '1', '1', '0'), ('1', '0', '1', '1', '1'), ('1', '1', '0', '0', '0'), ('1', '1', '0', '0', '1'), ('1', '1', '0', '1', '0'), ('1', '1', '0', '1', '1'), ('1', '1', '1', '0', '0'), ('1', '1', '1', '0', '1'), ('1', '1', '1', '1', '0'), ('1', '1', '1', '1', '1')]
```